# Unable to bring network interface eth0 back up after changing mac address with macchanger

Tags: linux, dhcp, kali-linux, network-interface

I couldn't find an answer for my issue, so I'm posting this.

I'm using Kali linux and when I successfully change my mac address using macchanger, I'm unable to bring my network interface eth0 back up.

I need help troubleshooting this issue.

Sequence of commands:

```
Checking default mac address:
# macchanger -s eth0

Stopping Network Manager:
# service network-manager stop

Changing mac address:
# macchanger -r eth0

Confirming the mac address change
# macchanger -s eth0

Starting Network-Manager
# service network-manager start

Network interface eth0 does not come back up.
# tail -f /var/log/messages
Jan 23 22:44:08 kali NetworkManager[4893]: <info>  [1485240248.3456] 

dhcp4 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jan 23 22:44:08 kali NetworkManager[4893]: <info>  [1485240248.3670] dhcp4 (eth0): dhclient started with pid 4932
Jan 23 22:44:53 kali NetworkManager[4893]: <warn>  [1485240293.3168] dhcp4 (eth0): request timed out
Jan 23 22:44:53 kali NetworkManager[4893]: <info>  [1485240293.3208] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jan 23 22:44:53 kali NetworkManager[4893]: <info>  [1485240293.3244] dhcp4 (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 4932
Jan 23 22:44:53 kali NetworkManager[4893]: <info>  [1485240293.3244] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed timeout -> done
Jan 23 22:44:53 kali NetworkManager[4893]: <info>  [1485240293.3281] device (eth0): Scheduling DHCPv4 restart because the connection is assumed

# cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=none

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

It seems a DHCP issue, but I haven't change the DHCP configuration file. It's the default that comes with Kali linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a correctly formatted MAC address? It has the I/G and U/L bits set correctly?

Comment: It should be correct. I don't think macchanger -r eth0 would create a wrong format, besides I know this command works for a lot of people.

Comment: Well, to what did it set the MAC address? It is a simple matter to look and see if the bits are set correctly.

Comment: It set to b6:ae:ba:aa:7b:8b